# Mann-Whitney U test significant; t- test not significant. How do I interpret this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have done both a t-test and a Mann-Whitney U test to test significance of the difference between two groups.

From my understanding a Mann-Whitney U test can be used in case my data is not "normal" enough. No looking at my results I have a t-test resulting in a p-value = 0.06 (which I'd deem significant) and a Mann-Whitney U test resulting in a p-value = 0.3 (which is not significant).

How do I interpret this? How do I proceed?

Comment: This is a good example of the benefits of choosing the test before looking at the data or, at the very least, having a principled program for determining the test.  You don't describe such a program because you haven't explained what "normal enough" might mean or how you made that determination here.  The next step, then, might be to explain these details of your situation.

Comment: Apparently the significance depends on assumptions the t-test makes but the U-test does not. Worth considering whether you can rely on those. Also please give the total number oy units in the groups.

Comment: @Bernhard I think in the context of specific data it would be simply that the sample proportion where (X>Y) doesn't differ much from 1/2 even though the means are more substantially different. This can happen easily enough with particular sample arrangements which might arise even in a case where all the *population* assumptions of both tests are simultaneously satisfied (assumptions are about the population the sample was supposedly drawn from, rather than the sample itself).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

First, a Mann Whitney U test can be used regardless of the normality of the data; the real question is whether a t-test can be used.

Second, U and t ask different questions, so it's not surprising that they give different answers. Specifically, while t tests compare means; the MW U test asks whether it is equally likely that a value from one sample will be greater or lesser than a value from the other distribution.

If the distributions are normal, then the two are sort of equivalent - that is, the answer to both questions will be either yes or no -  but the p values could differ (yet another problem with p values). But if the distributions are not normal, and particularly if they are not symmetric, the two questions could get very different answers.